# What does this Ghostscript unrecoverable error means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ghostscript

While tyring to compress the large pdf file using ghostscript command on rails I am getting an error.

```
input_file = oldpath(myfile)
`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=#{newpath(myfile)} input_file`
```

Error:

**GPL Ghostscript 9.15: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1**

Answer (score 0):

It means 'something went wrong and the interpreter couldn't recover'.

See [Ghostscript bug #695800](http://Ghostscript%20bug%20#695800)